# Field Calculator: Round UP to the nearest thousand

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a `cost` field in a table that I do field calculations on. The field contains values like:

- 1,000
- 2,100.00
- 3,500.99
- 4,900

I would like to use the field calculator to round the values **up** to the nearest thousand (unless the number is already rounded to the nearest thousand):

- 1,000.00
- 3,000.00
- 4,000.00
- 5,000.00

How can I do this with python in the field calculator?

Comment: Divmod(x,1000)[0] + (divmod(x,1000)>0). Times 1000. Should work for positive numbers.

Comment: A related question here, but for VBScript: [VBScript: Round number UP to nearest thousand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454073/vbscript-round-number-up-to-nearest-thousand/46454595#46454595)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
-(-!cost!//1000)*1000
```